# ruby if X is not equal to Y or Z then

Tags: ruby

I have the following:

```
a_disposition = [nil,'test','demo']

a_volume = a_disposition.count{|x| x != nil}
```

I want to count all values that are NOT `nil` and NOT `'test'`. What is the ruby way of saying `count where x is not nil and x is not 'test'`? I am using ruby 2.0.

Comment: `!x.nil? && x != 'test'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(a_disposition-[nil,'test']).count # => 1
```

Comment: Perfect, perfetto, parfait, perfekt, perfecto, 完ぺき, 完美, 완전한 !

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. It's not super performant, but it has nice functional touch. :)

```
a_disposition = [nil,'test','demo']

a_volume = a_disposition.reject(&:nil?).reject{|d| d == 'test'}.count # => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`a_disposition.compact.reject{ |x| x == 'test' }.count`

Answer (score 0):

I think using the count method with a block is the cleanest way:

```
a_disposition.count{|x| !x.nil? && x != 'test'}
```